# Black molly male attacking female

Tags: behavior, aquarium, fish, aggression

We have 3 female black mollies. 2 black ones which have turned a bit silvery/whiteish.  Originally, we had one male which had the same colour, but we noticed it will be dying soon (swimming upside down time and again).  We added a new male (completely black).  It got harassed by the other male, which died within a handful days.

Now, with the new male and 3 females, I notice the male acts normally towards the black ones. However, the silvery one (colored similarly to the dead male, with her lower fin being very dark on the outer part that makes it look similar to the male's part if you don't look closely) gets permanently attacked by the male and chased through the aquarium. He also makes dominance shows as if she was another male.

Is there anything we can do to resolve the situation without one of them dying?

Comment: Do you habe plants and other pbjects the attacked female can hide from the view of the male? If not you should add this as first aid, then both can rest

Comment: @Allerleirauh yepp there are a lot of plants and 4 "caves" even. but she is out in the open almost the whole time. sometimes she is biting him even (but very seldomly) but the other times he sees her and goes into attack mode. Interestingly over 5h of watching the two I noticed ONE single occasion where he had a behaviour in regards to her that he has for normal females (a soft peck on the underbelly which I have seen other males do). But 10 seconds later...next attack on her. He even ignores the other females during the attacks

Comment: Male is now sporting 2 large wounds one of each side of the body near the side fins. So getting worse

Comment: sounds as you need to separate them :(

Comment: Problem is weekend and no 2 tanks.   So no chance to get them to become peaceful with esch other?

Comment: I am no expert in fish training. But you could move the female into a big water bowl for two days, you need to hold the temperature low (cold water stores oxygen much better), change 1/3 of the water once a day and feed better less than too much to hold the water clean. If possible you could also took some kind of grid into the tank, to divide it into two parts.